# How to configure Github to work with Concourse CI?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, cloud-foundry, concourse

What is the best way to configure Github with concourse CI, concourse is up and running on a box.

How do I go from declaring a pipeline.yml in a git repo to it automatically propagating to concourse server.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is broad enough that I might not address your complete issue in a StackOverflow answer, but I would direct you to the excellent "Flight School" tutorial, which gives step by step constructions on performing a Concourse build from a Git Repo:

https://concourse-ci.org/flight-school.html

Comment: This Start and Wayne Tutorial goes into a bit more depth, also good. https://github.com/starkandwayne/concourse-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Corby's suggestion.

If this is your first time using Concourse (sounds like it), then I suggest you start with a [local concourse instance using Vagrant](https://concourse.ci/vagrant.html).

The Concourse documentation site has some good [tutorials](https://concourse.ci/tutorials.html). [Concourse-tutorial from Stark & Wayne](https://github.com/starkandwayne/concourse-tutorial) were very helpful for me to learn concourse.

I have some basic Spring boot projects with Concourse pipelines. Give them a try.

- https://github.com/akoranne/kill-java,
- https://github.com/akoranne/rulesengine.

I would also advise that you join the [concourse-ci slack channel](https://concourseci.slack.com/archives/general). You will get lot of help.